# How to set the initial view controller after a successful login in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My storyboard layout is like this:

navigationcontroller -> logincontroller -> tabbarcontroller -> first/second/third view controller

What I really want to do is to show the Tabbarcontroller after a successful login the next time when user launches the app.Plus, I've searched for a lot of solutions and most ones showed to use

```
rootView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainView") as UITabBarController        
window.rootViewController = mytabbarcontroller
```

and many reminded that this will break the segues.

I really don't know how to do that,please help me out!

Comment: What do you mean "this will break the segues"? Which segues would it break?

Comment: Right now, it seems fine. But some warned me that it would somehow break the followed segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

`didFinishlaunching` method of `AppDelegate` use some bool to check if the login session is active.
Based on that choose you `rootViewController`